# How do I get the coordinates of the mxGraph map?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, coordinates, mxgraph

In the mxgraph engine, I found the mouse event, but it doesn't reflect the actual map coordinate.
Here is a sample code where evt doesn't fit me.
We need a different solution. We need to get the map coordinate. We can check this by getting negative coordinates (probably).

In general, the task looks like this: the user selects a category of objects, he is shown a modal window with available SVG icons for placement. After the SVG click, the icon is placed in the place where the user clicks. I know that there is a possibility of standard Drag&Drop in mxGraph, but it does not suit us because of the specifics of the project.

```
    import {ref} from "vue";
    
    let dialogVisible = ref(false)
    let dialogConfirmed = ref(false)
    let selectedItem = ref(false)
    let dialogPromise = ref({
        resolve: () => {}
        reject: () => {}
    });
    
    export function useDialog(){
        return {
            dialogConfirmed,
            dialogVisible,
            selectedItem,
            dialogPromise
        }
    }
```

The code below shows the coordinates that we found in mxGraph, but they do not allow us to place the object on click.

```
    this.graph.addListener(MxEvent.CLICK, function(sender, evt)){
        console.log('evtOffsetX: ', evt.properties.event.offsetX)
        console.log('evtOffsetY: ', evt.properties.event.offsetY)
    }
    
    
    this.graph.getSelectionModel().addListener(MxEvent.CHANGE, function(vertex)){
        console.log('vertexCenterX: ', vertex.cells[0].geometry.getCenterX());
        console.log('vertexCenterY: ', vertex.cells[0].geometry.getCenterY());
        console.log('vertexHeight: ', vertex.cells[0].geometry.height);
        console.log('vertexWidth: ', vertex.cells[0].geometry.width);
        console.log('vertexX: ', vertex.cells[0].geometry.x);
        console.log('vertexY: ', vertex.cells[0].geometry.y);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on mxgraph 4.2.2 and it worked:

```
this.graph.addListener(mxEvent.CLICK, function(sender, evt) {
  console.log("GRAPH CLICK EVENT", sender, evt);
  var parent = sender.getDefaultParent();
  sender.getModel().beginUpdate();
  sender.insertVertex(parent, null, 'TEST', evt.getProperty("event").offsetX, evt.getProperty("event").offsetY, 80, 30);
  sender.getModel().endUpdate();
  evt.consume();
});
```

Comment: Everything is ok bro, but we would like to save this coordinate to automate